# How can i install development libraries for 'icu-le' and 'icu-uc'?

Tags: 12.04

I get this when I try to compile 'harfbuzz'.

```
No package 'icu-le' found
No package 'icu-uc' found
```

i have tried 'sudo apt-get install libicu-uc. But that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you look in synaptic  ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all you need are the development libraries, try installing `libicu-dev` and if you need the actual library, the name is `libicu48`.

```
apt-cache search libicu
```

This did the trick.

So:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```